# Reducing row reference by 1 for each for loop iteration in R

Tags: r, function

I'm working on a formula in R, that iterates over a data frame in reverse. Right now, the formula will take a set number of columns, and find the mean for each column, up to a set row number. What I'd like to do is have the row number decrease by 1 for each iteration of the for loop. The goal here is to create a "triangular" reference that uses one less value for the column means, per iteration.

Here's some code you can use to create sample data that works in the formula.

```
test = data.frame(p1 = c(1,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0), p2 = c(0,0,1,2,0,1,2,1,0,1))
```

Here's the function I'm working with. My best guess is that I'll need to add some sort of reference to `i` in the `mean(data[1:row, i])` section, but I can't seem to work the logic/math out on my own.

```
averagePickup = function(data, day, periods) {
  # data will be your Pickup Data
  # day is the day you're forecasting for (think row number)
  # periods is the period or range of periods that you need to average (a column or range of columns).
   pStart = ncol(data)
   pEnd = ncol(data) - (periods-1)
   row = (day-1)
   new_frame <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = periods))

  for(i in pStart:pEnd) {
    new_frame[1,1+abs(ncol(data)-i)] <- mean(data[1:row , i])
  }
  return(sum(new_frame[1,1:ncol(new_frame)]))
}
```

Right now, inputing `averagePickup(test,5,2)` will yield a result of 1.75. This is the sum of the means for the first 4 values of the two columns. What I'd like the result to be is 1.33333. This would be the sum of the mean of the first 4 values in column p1, and the mean of the first 3 values in column p2.

Please let me know if you need any further clarification, I'm still a total scrub at R!!!

Comment: Your function works up to periods = 10. You only have 10 columns so you can't go past that in mean(data[1:row , i]). I think I know what you mean but your rectangular data structure won't let you make a triangle

Comment: @stephen, thanks for your response. I think my description was pretty poor, I don't actually want to create a triangular data structure. Instead, I just want the triangular reference to those values. The sample data only has 10 periods for simplicity, in reality there's a period for each day in a year. What I'm looking for is to have the `mean` function use one less row per additional period. I'm going to update the question with new test data and an explanation of what my expected result _should_ be so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I ended up figuring it out with a few more head bashes against the wall. Here's what worked for me:

```
averagePickup = function(data, day, periods) {
  # data will be your Pickup Data
  # day is the day you're forecasting for (think row number)
  # periods is the period or range of periods that you need to average (a column or range of columns).
  pStart = ncol(data)
  pEnd = ncol(data) - (periods-1)
  row = (day-1)
  new_frame <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = periods))

  q <- 0 # Instantiated a q value. Run 0 will be the first one.
  for(i in pStart:pEnd) {
    new_frame[1,1+abs(ncol(data)-i)] <- mean(data[1:(day - periods + q) , i]) # Added a subtraction of q from the row number to use.
    q <- q + 1 # Incrementing q, so the next time will use one less row.
  }
   return(sum(new_frame[1,1:ncol(new_frame)]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
test = data.frame(p1 = c(1,2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0), p2 = c(0,0,1,2,0,1,2,1,0,1))
averagePickup = function(data, first, second) {
  return(mean(test[1:first,1]) + mean(test[1:second,2]))
}

averagePickup(test,4,3)
```

This gives you 1.333333

Comment: Not quite. The formula needs to be more dynamic so any number of periods or rows could be input to the function. The actual data I'll be using this formula on will likely have thousands of rows and columns. Additionally, the reduction in the number of rows needs to happen for _each_ additional column that's included in the sum. This formula would only work for 2 columns, and would also require that I build a new argument for each additional column.